# How to implement yes-no radiobuttons in a listview (WPF)?

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, radio-button

I have a listview which has a field for question and two radio button -yes and no. I want to add the response for each question to database. I am unable to do so.

This is what I have tried -

Part of the XAML code(the listview is inside stackpanel) -

```
<ListView HorizontalAlignment="Left" x:Name="listviewQue" Background="Azure" 
         ItemsSource="{Binding Questions}" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False" SelectionMode="Multiple">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <DockPanel>
                        <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Top" x:Name="quebox" Text="{Binding que_text}"
                 Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=textblock_style }" />
                        <RadioButton GroupName="answergrp" Click="Yesradiobtn_Click" x:Name="yesradiobtn" DockPanel.Dock="Left">yes</RadioButton>
                        <RadioButton GroupName="answergrp" Click="Noradiobtn_Click" x:Name="noradiobtn" DockPanel.Dock="Right">no</RadioButton>
                    </DockPanel>


                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>

        </ListView>
```

Code behind :

```
private void Yesradiobtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            string ans = "yes";
            Question q = new Question();
            q = listviewQue.SelectedItem as Question;
            string res = SQLiteDataAccess.AddResponse(surveryId, emp[empIndex].Id, q.que_id, ans);
            if (!(res == SQLiteDataAccess.SUCCESS))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("SQLite Exception for 'yes' radiobutton click " + res);
            }
        }

        private void Noradiobtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            string ans = "no";
            Question q = new Question();
            q = listviewQue.SelectedItem as Question;
            string res = SQLiteDataAccess.AddResponse(surveryId, emp[empIndex].Id, q.que_id, ans);
            if (!(res == SQLiteDataAccess.SUCCESS))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("SQLite Exception for 'no' radiobutton click : " + res);
            }
        }
```

This is sqlite function for inserting into database:

```
public static string AddResponse(string sid,string eid,int qid,string answer)
        {
            try
            {
                using (IDbConnection cnn = new SQLiteConnection(LoadConnectionString()))
                {
                    cnn.Execute("insert into RESPONSE values ('" + sid + "','" + eid + "'," + qid + ",'" + answer + "')");
                }
                return SUCCESS;
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                return FAILURE +": exception e = "+e;
            }
        }
```

The exception message which I m getting is -

```
\System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

q was null.
```

How can I achieve it ?

**Update** The Question class -

```
namespace Version2._0
{
    public class Question
    {
        public int que_id { get; set; }
        public string que_text { get; set; }

        private bool isSelected;
        public bool IsSelected
        {
            get { return isSelected; }
            set
            {
                isSelected = value;
                 // SQLiteDataAccess.AddResponse(surveryId, emp[empIndex].Id, item.que_id, ans);
                // how can I get the surveyId and emp[empIndex].Id here
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't be using Click event handlers at all. Instead, bind the IsChecked property of one of the RadioButtons to a boolean property in your Question class. Then react on changes of that property in your view model.

Comment: oh! I have a``` public Boolean IsSelected { get; set; }``` in my Question class , how can I use that here with radiobuttons?

Comment: `<RadioButton Content="Yes" IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected}" ... />`

Comment: For both yes and no radio buttons i need to do that ??Like wont it be same? I need to insert in the database as soon as a radio button is clicked for a question , how can I do that in the backend ?I m not so well versed in this , excuse me if i asked a silly question .

Comment: The buttons are in a group, so if you check one, the other will be unchecked. So as said before, bind the IsChecked property of one of the RadioButtons.

Comment: okay and what method should be implemented in the back so that when a radiobutton is clicked for a particular question , insertion in database should take place ?

Comment: Put the necessary code in the setter of the IsSelected property.

Comment: `<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                    <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected}" />
                </Style>
            </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>`
Like this?

Comment: No, please find the binding in my previous comment. Setter of the IsSelected property means the property in your Question class. You know what the setter of a C# property is?

Comment: oh sorry ! U mean like this - 
` 
public Boolean IsSelected {
            get { return IsSelected; }
            set { // my code goes here 
            }
        }
`

Comment: Except that `return IsSelected` would be `return isSelected`, i.e. use the property's backing field. Otherwise you'd get a StackOverflowException.

Comment: I m a bit stuck now.Can you explain with a simple example considering my need? Like how I should move ahead ? I m not understanding how I should make use of that for fetching which radio button is selected for a particular question

Comment: You don't need to know which RadioButton was clicked. The IsSelected property already changes its value on the appropriate Question object.

Comment: for `how can I get the surveyId and emp[empIndex].Id here?` - we can't tell, because we don't know what it is. And that is certainly out of the scope of the question.

Comment: okay ! Considering my need , can u suggest a way to achieve it ?? Else I will have drop the idea of implementing it this way :(

Comment: Add this data as properties to your Question class? How can we possibly tell?

Comment: See the edit I made in your question. As a note, I think you don't need to set or bind GroupName at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I solved it , all thanks to @Clemens(Thanks a lot!) 
My Questions class -

```
public class Question
{
    public int que_id { get; set; }
    public string que_text { get; set; }
    public Boolean IsSelected { get; set; }
 }
```

My XAML part :

```
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <DockPanel>
                    <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Top" x:Name="quebox" Text="{Binding que_text}"
             Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=textblock_style }" />
                    <RadioButton  IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected}" x:Name="yesradiobtn" DockPanel.Dock="Left">yes</RadioButton>
                    <RadioButton   x:Name="noradiobtn" DockPanel.Dock="Right">no</RadioButton>
                </DockPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

And I m inserting into database on a button click after selecting all the answers like this-

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        List<Question> items = (List<Question>)listviewQue.ItemsSource;
        int count = 0;
        int totalcnt = items.Count;
        foreach (Question item in items)
        {
            if (item.IsSelectedRadioBtn)
            {
                count++;
                string ans = "yes";
                string res = SQLiteDataAccess.AddResponse(surveryId, emp[empIndex].Id, item.que_id, ans);
                if (!(res == SQLiteDataAccess.SUCCESS))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("SQLite Exception for 'yes' radiobutton click " + res);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                count++;
                string ans = "no";
                string res = SQLiteDataAccess.AddResponse(surveryId, emp[empIndex].Id, item.que_id, ans);
                if (!(res == SQLiteDataAccess.SUCCESS))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("SQLite Exception for 'no' button click " + res);
                }
            }
        }
        if (count != totalcnt)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter the response for all the questions");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Response recorded successfully");
        }

    }
```

Comment: As a note, you don't need the backing field of the IsSelectedRadioBtn property now. Just revert to an auto property like `public bool IsSelectedRadioBtn { get; set; }`. And why are there two bool properties `IsSelected` and `IsSelectedRadioBtn` now? That doesn't seem to make sense. Also note that `bool` and `Boolean` are identical types. You typically only use the `bool` keyword.

Comment: Oh i forgot about that temporary boolean variable i had created ! I removed it now :) Thanks a ton!